# Not receiving complaint notifications. It works with the simulator - AWS SES Events

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-sqs, amazon-ses

AWS SES
I am creating a new application that will eventually send a lot of emails. Right now I can send emails using the API and I am receiving send and return notifications through SNS. Complaint notifications are processed correctly using the simulator (complaint@simulator.amazonses.com), but I don't get anything when I test gmail or outlook, or my company email accounts. I have enabled email notifications for testing, but this gives the same result. The simulator works testing complaint events. I can receive the events Sends, deliveries, openings and clicks using different emails

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

SES has something called a sandbox. For you to be able to send emails to domains that are not trusted and specifically added in SES service, you have to go out of this mode:

Follow Amazon instructions to go into production mode: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

Comment: I have production mode enabled, I can send emails to different accounts but I cannot receive the complaint event, using gmail or outlook. the simulator if it sends the complaint event.